# Same cells (formatting, formulae and all the rest) across 32 sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I need to have the same headings for the daily report table (31 sheets in one file and a 32nd one for totals). From time to time I need to add a column, or change formatting.

Is there a way I can have some range of cells to be the same across all the sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the sheets by:

1. clicking the first sheet,
2. going to the last sheet by clicking the arrow: [image],
3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the last sheet (you should see the colour of the sheets turning a bit lighter; they are all selected),
4. Do the necessary edits on that last sheet.

You will notice that, depending on the size of the workbook, that it will take longer for updates, that's because the same things are being applied to all the sheets at the same time. You might want to make a copy first to see how it works.

Remember to click any other sheet when you edit a value in a cell if this value is to get updated in one sheet only to deselect all the sheets, otherwise, all your sheets will get updated by the same value.